# Combine two DAX-measures in Power Pivot

Tags: powerpivot, measure, dax

I have two calculated measures, one that calculates number of new customers for each month and another that calculates transaction values for each month. Is it possible to combine the two measures to, for example, calculate the transaction value but only for the new customers?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think I solved it. I may have been unclear about what I was doing and I was thinking in wrong direction. I was using [Marco Russos formula](http://www.daxpatterns.com/new-and-returning-customers/) for new customers and instead of counting rows for customers I simply changed it to calcuate transaction value. Now it looks something like this:

```
Test:=CALCULATE([Transaction Value SEK]; (
   FILTER (
       ADDCOLUMNS (
           VALUES ( MonthlyStatistics[Mid] );
            "PreviousSales"; CALCULATE (
               COUNTROWS (MonthlyStatistics);
               FILTER (
                ALL ( 'Date' );
                'Date'[Date] < MIN ( 'Date'[Date] )
            )
        )
    );
    [PreviousSales] = 0
)
))
```